# How do I determine the equation when I have two inputs and the output?

Tags: linear-algebra, curves

*x* and *y* are whole numbers 1 through 10. The output is values from 100 to 10.

Here's a screenshot of the inputs and outputs in a table. How would I go about determining a formula that fits this?

[Table of inputs and outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkFVL.png)

Comment: I would start with a good plot (easily generated in Excel),

Comment: @almagest Wouldn't this generate a 3D graph since we are dealing with _x_, _y_, and _z_ as the output? How would that help?

Comment: In general what you're interested in is Curve Fitting. Excel has built-in curve fitting, for instance.

Comment: @dbx It does, when you are dealing with a single input. I have two variables here. The closest answer I have found to my question so far is [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103038/multiple-regression-curve-fitting) but I think their question is a little more complicated than mine.

Comment: A surface plot (geogebra, matlab, online stuff - look it up) would help people visualize it and perhaps recognize it or give useful suggestions. That is work for you to do though.

Comment: @Paul Thank you for the starting point. geobra and matlab seem to be what I need here and where I should begin. I think multilinear regression plays a role here as well.